# The method 'put' isn't defined for the type '_GetImpl'

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I was trying to use GetX state management but while creating reference of `ShoppingController` in `indexPage` like `final shoppingController = Get.put(ShoppingController());` I get the error like `error: The method 'put' isn't defined for the type '_GetImpl'.`

This is index_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:statemanagement/controller/shopping_contrller.dart';

class indexPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final shoppingController = Get.put(ShoppingController());

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return Card();
                  }),
            ),
            Text("Total amount: "),
            SizedBox(height: 100.0,)
          ],
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

shopping_controller.dart

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:statemanagement/model/product.dart';

class ShoppingController extends GetxController {
  var productList = <Product>[].obs;

@override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    fetchProduct();
  }

  void fetchProduct() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    var productResult = [
      Product(
          id: 1,
          productName: 'First Product',
          productImage: 'abcd.jpg',
          productDescription: 'This is some kid of description of the image',
          price: 30),
      Product(
          id: 2,
          productName: 'Second Product',
          productImage: 'bcd.img',
          productDescription: 'THisis some kind of second image description',
          price: 40
      ),
      Product(
          id: 3,
          productName: 'third Product',
          productImage: 'bcd.img',
          productDescription: 'THisis some kind of third image description',
          price: 40
      )
    ];
    productList.value = productResult;
  }
}
```

product.dart

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String productName;
  final String productImage;
  final String productDescription;
  final double price;

  Product(
      {required this.id,
      required this.productName,
      required this.productImage,
      required this.productDescription,
      required this.price});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong import library for Get, try importing this "Getx" library.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case by using the 'get' package as library sorted the issue

1. In the pubspec.yaml add the 'get' :

   get: 4.1.4
2. Then, import it in your project file using statement:

   import 'package:get/get.dart';
3. Remove cache, in some cases and run the project

The error should now go.